# first column of table jumping out of overflow-y:auto;

Tags: css, html-table

I have verticle and horizontal scroll on my table but when I get to mobile sizes, the data begins to squish and my first column jumps out of the div and I have no idea why. Here is my css:

```
table, th, td {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. The site I am working on is https://probeis.mx/deteccion
and here is a screenshot showing the problem:
[image]

Comment: Can u plz remove this "<div class="table-data"></div>" and check once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mobile resolution (under 700px cases) you have set `position:absolute;` in `.table-rank tr td:first-child`. That causes the breakage.

You have to remove that `position:absolute` and also no need to set `top`.

```
@media (max-width: 700px)
.table-rank tr td:first-child {
    width: 160px;
    position: initial;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much. now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**css**

```
@media only screen and(max-width: 700px){
   position: static;
}
```